# Axiom of Replacement (Question of notation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each formula $\phi$ without $Y$ free, the universal closure of the following is an axiom:

$\forall x\in A \exists !y \phi(x,y) \Longrightarrow \exists Y \forall x\in A \exists y\in Y \phi(x,y)$

My question is about the $!$, does that mean that $y$ is bound in $\phi$?  What does the exclamation mark mean? Is it there so that $y\ne \{x: x\not\in x \}$? I am confused.

Comment: "There is a unique"

Comment: (But it is not needed, we can relax the requirement to the usual $\exists$, and the new schema is equivalent to this one.)

Comment: I see. Thank you that makes things more clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rustyn, $\exists !$ is the quantifier "there is a unique". This is just an abbreviation, as it can be defined in terms of the standard quantifiers: $\exists! x\psi(x)$ is just $\exists x(\psi(x)\land\forall y(\psi(y)\to y=x))$.

Anyway, this version of replacement (where the graph of $\phi$ is a "function") is equivalent to the more generous version where the $\exists!$ is replaced by the usual $\exists$ (where the graph of $\phi$ is just a "relation").

Comment: I see, they didn't introduce this abbreviation in the book, so I was confused.

Comment: Some people prefer the abbreviation $\exists^{=1}$ instead.

Comment: It's not clear to me how to derive the "more generous" version from the usual one, at least not without some kind of choice principle. (Sure, we could add more than one $y$ per $x$ to $Y$, but if we add too many of them we risk the result being too large to be a set, don't we?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm You minimize the rank of the witnesses $y$. (One useful way of thinking of replacement is saying that any function with a set domain has *bounded* -as opposed to cofinal- range.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Makes sense -- assuming we have Regularity.

Comment: The more "generous" version is the axiom of collection, no?

Comment: @ZhenLin [Sure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Axiom_schema_of_collection).