# Trying to understand how to read ∃!

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I have to find the negation of ∃!x∈U[p(x)]

I believe I need to rewrite the equation in a format not using ∃! so that I can find its negation. There is what I have come up with, but I am not sure if it is correct.

∃x∈U[P(x) ∧ ∀(y) -> (y = x)]

Am I on the right track with this?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/480789/462).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the expression that you’ve written doesn’t actually make sense: $\forall y$ is not an expression that can imply anything. What you’re trying to say, I take it, is that there is an $x$ with the property $P$ and which is such that any $y$ with the property $P$ must be this same $x$; that’s

$$\exists x\in U\Big(P(x)\land\forall y\in U\big(P(y)\to y=x\big)\Big)\;.$$

(There are other, equivalent expressions as well, but that seems closest to the idea that you had in mind.)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you have written. I'll copy this to my notes and make sure I understand it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tony: You’re welcome; feel free to ping me with a comment if you have any further questions about it.

Comment: Hi Brian, By "ping me", do you mean a private email or through here?

Comment: @Tony: Through here; a comment left under my answer automatically leaves a message in my inbox here.

Comment: Hi, so I have written out what I believe is the negation of this statement and was wondering if you would mind letting me if it is correct? This is what I have: ∀x∈U(P(x)∨∃y∈U(p(y)∧y ≠ x))

Comment: @Tony: You’re missing one negation: $$\forall x\in U\Big(\neg P(x)\lor\exists y\in U\big(P(y)\land y\ne x\big)\Big)$$

Comment: Right, because the negation of a (p ∧ q) statement is (~p ∨ ~q). Thanks again, Brian. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Tony: You’re very welcome.